# Segmentation fault: 11 when printing out of a loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

First of all say that I have been looking for information on the network, making tests with gdb debugging and...nothing...I still do not understand the error, I get the idea that it might come from the "getline" instruction, but I'm not sure...

The main idea of the code is to read line by line and convert chars strings into floats and save the floats in a array called `nfloat` and then call the function: *create_table* to create an array of pointers of type vector.

The input is a `.txt` containing this: *n* = the number of strings, in this case *n* = 3

```
3
[9.3,1.2,87.9]
[1.0,1.0]
[0.0,0.0,1.0]
```

The first number, `3` is the number of vectors as we can see in the image, but that number isn't static, the input can be `5` or `7`, etc instead of `3`.

So far, I've started doing the following, but the code has some memory errors I think:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
    float* data;
    int size;
} vector;




vector *create_vector(int n, float* comps){
    vector newvect;
    newvect.data = (float *) malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newvect.data[i] = comps[i];
        printf("Newvec.data[%d] = %.1f\n", i, newvect.data[i]);
    }
    newvect.size = n;
    vector *pointvector;
    pointvector = &newvect;
    return(pointvector);
}


int NumsVector(char *linea, ssize_t size){
    int numsvector = 1; 
    int n;
    for(n = 2; n<= size; n++){ 
        if (linea[n] != '[' && linea[n] != ']'){
            if(linea[n] == 44){
                numsvector = numsvector + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return numsvector;
}

int main(){
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    vector *v[n];
    for(i = 0; i<n; ++i) { 
        char *line = NULL; 
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read; 
        read = getline(&line,&len,stdin);
        int numsvector = NumsVector(line, read);
        float nfloat[numsvector];
        int j = 0;
        /* Replaces the end ] with a , */
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = ',';

        /* creates a new pointer, pointing after the first [ in the original string */
        char *p = line + 1;
        do
        {
            /* grabs up to the next comma as a float */
            sscanf(p, "%f,", &nfloat[j]);
            /* moves pointer forward to next comma */
            while (*(p++) != ',');
        }
        while (++j < numsvector); /* stops when you've got the expected number */
        v[i] = create_vector(numsvector, nfloat);
        printf("%f\n", v[i]->data[1]); //prints ok :)!
        free(line);
    }
    printf("%f\n", v[i]->data[1]); //segmentation fault:11 :(!! }
```

Well, the problems come with the printf instructions I think, when I print inside the loop, everything works fine but when I try to do the same out of the for loop, it prints the segmentation fault error...might be some memory leak?

is important for me to know if *v[n] is well implemented and stores well the information in order to keep creating functions based on the *v[n] information.

Please could someone help me understand where is the problem when I print out the loop?

Comment: your create_vector() function is returning the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector *pointvector;
pointvector = &newvect;
return(pointvector);
```

You're returning pointer to local variable. This is incorrect and needs to be changed either by allocating dynamic memory for `newvect` or by using `static` variable within function and then copying data (data wouldn't persist between two calls).

Edit: as requested, example with dynamic allocation:

```
vector *create_vector(int n, float* comps){
    vector *newvect = malloc(sizeof(*newvect));
    newvect->data = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    memcpy(newvect->data, comps, sizeof(float) * n);
    newvect->size = n;
    return newvector;
}
```

Of course at some point you'll need to free both data and vector itself.

Comment: @user4815162342 the return must be a `vector *` :(

Comment: @keltar Can you give an example of how the code would look like by allocating dynamic memory?

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but I get a compilation error:

`eda.c:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘vector*’
eda.c:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’`

What can we do to make it work?

Comment: @Gerard what compiler is it? Have you manually forced C++ mode? In C, no compiler is allowed to complain about conversion from void* to any other pointer type. In C++, however, they _must_ complain. So, if you for some reason in C++ mode, you need to cast malloc's return value to your intended type (e.g. `vector *newvect = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(*newvect));`, same goes for float*). This is, however, very strange to force C++ mode for C code.

Comment: We are required to write the code in C and compile it with g++ ...
My college professor should be special ... anyway, now works properly! many thanks: D

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
printf("%f\n", v[i]->data[1]); //segmentation fault:11 :(!! }
```

`i` equals `n`. And as `v` is declared `v[n]` the above line provokes undefined behaviour by accessing `v` out of bounds.

---

To get around the issue of returning an address to a local variable do like this:

```
vector * create_vector(size_t n, float * comps)
{
  vector * newvect = malloc(sizeof(*newvect);
  if (NULL != newvect)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  newvect->data =  malloc(n * sizeof(*newvect->data));
  if (NULL != newvect->data)
  {
    free(newvect);
    return NULL;
  }

  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  {
    newvect->data[i] = comps[i];
    printf("newvect->data[%zu] = %.1f\n", i, newvect->data[i]);
  }

  newvect->size = n;

  return newvect;
}
```

Comment: But if for example, `i = 0`, and I try to access `v [0]` which are values ​​within the limits ... Why is giving error anyway?

Comment: @Gerard: For the line in question (the one after the for-loop, as per my answer) `i` would never be `0`.

Comment: If I try to run a line without the variable "i" outside the loop, like this:

`printf("%f\n", v[0]->data[1]); //(outside the loop)`


The problem persists...I think the problem is what keltar says in the previous answer, but I do not understand exactly what he means by "by allocating dynamic memory for newvect"

Comment: @Gerard: The are at least two isses in your code: The one described by *keltar* and the one mentioned by me.